# Optimizing Node.js for a large number of outbound HTTP requests?

Tags: node.js

My node.js server is experiencing times when it becomes slow or unresponsive, even occasionally resulting in 503 gateway timeouts when attempting to connect to the server.

I am 99% sure (based upon tests that I have run) that this lag is coming specifically from the large number of outbound requests I am making with the [node-oauth module](https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth) to contact external APIs (Facebook, Twitter, and many others). Admittedly, the number of outbound requests being made is relatively large (in the order of 30 or so per minute). Even worse, this frequently means that the corresponding inbound requests to my server can take ~5-10 seconds to complete. However, I had a previous version of my API which I had written in PHP which was able to handle this amount of outbound requests without any problem at all. Actually, the CPU usage for the same number (or even fewer) requests with my Node.js API is about 5x that of my PHP API.

So, I'm trying to isolate where I can improve upon this, and most importantly to make sure that 503 timeouts do not occur. Here's some stuff I've read about or experimented with:

- This [article (by LinkedIn)](http://engineering.linkedin.com/nodejs/blazing-fast-nodejs-10-performance-tips-linkedin-mobile) recommends turning off socket pooling. However, when I contacted the author of the popular [nodejs-request module](https://github.com/mikeal/request), his response was that this was a very poor idea.
- I have heard it said that setting "http.globalAgent.maxSockets" to a large number can help, and indeed it did seem to reduce bottlenecking for me

I could go on, but in short, I have been able to find very little definitive information about how to optimize performance so these outbound connections do not lag my inbound requests from clients.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts or contributions.

FWIW, I'm using express and mongoose as well, and my servers are hosted on the Amazon Cloud (2x M1.Large for the node servers, 2x load balancers, and 3x M1.Small MongoDB instances).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me that the Agent is capping your requests to the default level of 5 per-host.  Your tests show that cranking up the agent's `maxSockets` helped...  you should do that.

You can prove this is the issue by firing up a packet sniffer, or adding more debugging code to your application, to show that this is the limiting factor.

Comment: I already have the globalAgent.maxSockets set to a very high number (9999), and the issue persists (this helped, but did not fix the problem). Is there somewhere else I should be changing the maxSockets value? Because I can't see how else to improve this.

Comment: You need to further debug this issue.  Are you sure that the problem isn't simply that your 3rd parties are taking longer to respond?  Do you have any logging in your application to show where the hang up is?  You need more information.  Also, by setting `maxSockets` to `9999`, you have effectively turned off socket pooling.  Why not just turn off socket pooling?

Comment: Good point about socket pooling ;) It may very well be the case that the 3rd parties are taking a while to respond, which is fine. But the issue is that while these connections are active, my inbound connections are resulting in 503 gateway timeouts... even connections that make no outbound requests. For example: inbound-connection-1 is using oAuth and taking a long time, inbound-connection-2 just wants to hit the MongoDB, but it results in a timeout due to inbound-connection-1. I'm not quite sure on how I would debug this though... I know #1 is busy and #2 timed out, where would I add log()s?

Comment: I don't know how to help you.  You say you are CPU-bound, but have no code.  I have no idea what you have in front of Node throwing 503s, nor any idea on the configuration of whatever that is.  Add debug logging everywhere and narrow it down.  Every function call if you have to.  You know your code... you probably have guesses as to where the problem is.  If you aren't logging anything, you have nothing to go off of.

Comment: Sigh, I guess you're right. I'm logging plenty, it's more a problem of that I have "logging overload." When operating at this scale (thousands of requests per minute) I have a hard time figuring out how to effectively create/parse/analyze logs. I guess I need to find a good article on that subject ;)

Comment: Check this out:  http://dtrace.org/blogs/dap/2012/01/05/where-does-your-node-program-spend-its-time/

Comment: Woah, this is made of pure awesomeness. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

http://engineering.linkedin.com/nodejs/blazing-fast-nodejs-10-performance-tips-linkedin-mobile

Disable the agent altogether.